# Random Forest using pyspark.ml for Dataframes

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, random-forest, apache-spark-ml

I am trying to build a random forest classifier using pyspark.ml library for dataframes (**not mllib for RDD**).
Do I have to use pipeline as given in the documentation?
I just want to construct a simple model,

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier(labelCol = labs, featuresCol = rawdata)
```

I run into the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/__init__.py", line 104, in wrapper
    return func(self, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/ml/classification.py", line 910, in __init
__
    self.setParams(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/__init__.py", line 104, in wrapper
    return func(self, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/ml/classification.py", line 928, in setPar
ams
    return self._set(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/ml/param/__init__.py", line 421, in _set
    raise TypeError('Invalid param value given for param "%s". %s' % (p.name, e)
)
TypeError: Invalid param value given for param "labelCol". Could not convert <cl
ass 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'> to string type
```

A sample of my labels

```
+---+
| _2|
+---+
|0.0|
|1.0|
|0.0|
|0.0|
|0.0|
|0.0|
|1.0|
|1.0|
|1.0|
|0.0|
|0.0|
|0.0|
|0.0|
|0.0|
|0.0|
|0.0|
|0.0|
|0.0|
|1.0|
|1.0|
+---+
```

My data is similar with 180 columns.

Comment: You do not *have* to use pipelines. For more help, please provide a sample of your data

Comment: I have edited the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Spark dataframes are not used like that in Spark ML; all your features need to be vectors in a *single* column, usually (but not necessarily) named `features`. Plus, `labelcol=labs` means that your labels need to be in a column named `labs`, and not `_2`.

Here is an example to get the idea, with toy data:

```python
spark.version
# u'2.2.0'

from pyspark.ml.classification import RandomForestClassifier
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
     (0.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 1.0)),
     (1.0, Vectors.dense(1.0, 0.0))], 
     ["label", "features"])

df.show() # notice there are only 2 columns, and 'features' is a 2-d vector
# +-----+---------+ 
# |label| features|
# +-----+---------+ 
# |  0.0|[0.0,1.0]|
# |  1.0|[1.0,0.0]|
# +-----+---------+

rf = RandomForestClassifier(numTrees=3, maxDepth=2, labelCol="label", seed=42)
rf_model = rf.fit(df)
```

[This answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46710934/pyspark-sql-utils-illegalargumentexception-ufield-features-does-not-exist/46729342#46729342) may be helpful in how to convert your data in the desired format.

Comment: I have been trying to do that but get the following error. 
in _parse_basic_datatype_string
    raise ValueError("Could not parse datatype: %s" % s)
ValueError: Could not parse datatype: features

Comment: @Nivi Can not make much of this... I suggest you gather the stuff and open a new question with the details